# Javascript: Using External Scripts

Tags: javascript

I am trying to import a simple script into an HTML doc. It won't work and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Name of external script--> (function.js)

```
window.onload = myFunction;

       function myFunction() 
       {
             document.getElementById("HERE").innerHTML = "message";
       }
```

name of HTML doc--> (attributes.html)

```
<!DOCTYPEhtml>

    <html>
    <head>

         <title> This is an example of using an external script</title> 
            <script type ="text/javascript" src= "function.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

          <h1 id="HERE"> 
          </h1>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Seems no problem with the code, did you get any errors?

Comment: Can you share the folder structure?

Comment: Is the `function.js` file located at the same directory level as `attributes.html`?

Comment: There must be some error you aren't showing us because it works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/H6dHG/.  Look in the browser error console and report what errors it shows.

Comment: Permissions are set correctly on file?

Comment: invalid character         function.js,line1character1

Comment: @dibs invalid character               function.js,line1 charcter1

Comment: Code is correct. We are not going naked for you thought!

Comment: @mplungjan Well I cant figure out why it won't import the script

Comment: Is your js file starting with <script> tag?

Comment: or atleast post your first line of function.js here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the body on load event fires too early, before js file go running.
Try to use "document.body.onload" at least of "window.onload".
Try to use "document.attachEvent":

```
document.attachEvent(document.body, "load", myFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

     <title> This is an example of using an external script</title> 
        <script type ="text/javascript" src= "function.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

      <h1 id="HERE"> 
      </h1>

     <script>myFunction() </script>
</body>
</html>
```